# How can I read and group this CSV data?

Tags: python, csv, python-ggplot

The csv looks like this. '|' means different columns.

```
2014-09-01 | I love chicken

2014-09-01 | I eat chicken

2014-09-02 | She loves chicken

2014-09-02 | Ha ha ha I love chicken

2014-09-03 | Blah Blah Blah
```

I want to treat the data so it would look like this.

```
2014-09-01 | 'i', 2 | 'love', 1 | 'chicken', 2 | 'eat', 1 |

2014-09-02 | 'she', 1 | 'love', 2 | 'chicken', 2 | 'ha', 3 | 'I', 1 |

2014-09-03 | 'blah', 3 |

DATE | WORD, WORDCOUNTS | WORD2, WORDCOUNTS2 | ...
```

What approach should I use here?  I ultimately want to plot a graph that shows Date on x-axis and word counts (frequency) on the y-axis.

Below is my best approach yet.

```
TestStartDate = "2013-11-11"
TestEndDate = "2014-06-10"

with open('Simplified.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if str(row[0:1])[2:12] == TestStartDate:
            #str(row[1:2])[2:str(row[1:2]).find('"')-1] is the second column
            tagger = MeCab.Tagger()
            rose = tagger.parse(str(row[1:2])[2:str(row[1:2]).find('"')-1])
            #print rose
            wordCount = {}
            wordList = rose.split()[:-1:2]
            for word in wordList:
                wordCount.setdefault(word, 0)
                wordCount[word] += 1
            for word, count in wordCount.items():
                print '"%s, %i"' % (word, count)
```

I plan to add word and count into Data.

Comment: do you have code you have written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me ~ and do you really need the last '|' ? because when you split it with '|' again when you put it into matplotlib or something else, you 'll get a '' in your result.

the code below will not append a '|' to each row of result, if you think it's necessary, just append a '|' to the function d, like this:

```
return '%s| %s|'%(tokens[0],'|'.join(["'%s',%s"%(word,words.count(word)) for word in set(words)]))
```

===========

```
def d(s):
    tokens = s.split('|')
    words = tokens[-1].strip().lower().split(' ')
    return '%s| %s'%(tokens[0],'|'.join(["'%s',%s"%(word,words.count(word)) for word in set(words)]))

def wordcount():
    lines=[
        '2014-09-01 | I love chicken',
        '2014-09-01 | I eat chicken',
        '2014-09-02 | She loves chicken',
        '2014-09-02 | Ha ha ha I love chicken',
        '2014-09-03 | Blah Blah Blah'
    ]
    rows={}
    for line in lines:
        t_line = line.split(' | ')
        if t_line[0] not in rows:
            rows[t_line[0]]=''
        rows[t_line[0]]+=(' '+t_line[-1])
    newrows=[]
    for k,v in rows.items():
        newrows.append(d('%s | %s'%(k,v)))
    print '\n'.join(newrows)


>>2014-09-02 | 'love',1|'i',1|'she',1|'loves',1|'chicken',2|'ha',3
>>2014-09-03 | 'blah',3
>>2014-09-01 | 'i',2|'chicken',2|'love',1|'eat',1
```

Comment: That is very good! I would really want to upvote this but I don't have enough 15 reputation. The '|' is just to let reader easily see that it separates each columns.

Answer (score 0):

Read the input CSV, creating a dictionary mapping the dates to `Counter`s.  Update the counter for the given data of each row with the words from that row.  Then write rows of the form [date, (word1, count1), (word2, count2), ...].  This example sorts the dates and words, but you can omit that for better performance.

```
from collections import Counter
import csv

data = {}

with open('my_data.csv') as f:
    for date, words in csv.reader(f, delimiter='|'):
        data.setdefault(date, Counter()).update(word for word in words.split())

with open('my_counts.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')

    for date in sorted(data.keys()):
        writer.writerow([date] + ["'{0}', {1}".format(date, data[date]) for date in sorted(data.keys())])
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `Counter` for counting.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

stats = {}

with open('in.txt' ,'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        tokens = re.split('[\| ]', line)
        key = tokens.pop(0)
        counter = Counter()
        for token in tokens:
            counter[token] = counter[token] + 1
        if key in stats:
            stats[key] = stats[key] + counter
        else:
            stats[key] = counter

for key, counter in stats.items():
    print key, '|', '|'.join([ '"%s", %s' % (k,v) for k,v in counter.items() ]), '|'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) collections.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter


date_words = defaultdict(lambda: Counter())


with open('test.csv') as psvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(psvfile, delimiter="|")

    for line in reader:
        date = line[0]
        words = line[1].split()

        date_words[date].update(Counter(words))
```

You might also want to consider using the pandas library that is good at handling dates and at plotting stuffs.